Telegram stops sending webhook updates
I have my Telegram bot deployed to GCP cloud run. It works fine even when instances get scaled to 0 - when Telegram calls, the instance starts and the bot receives the updates.
But sometimes, in unknown circumstances:

I send a message to the bot
No requests I have in GCP
The instances don't scale

What's interesting is that if I call the getWebhookInfo method:
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": {
    "url": "https://my-host/telegram/webhook",
    "has_custom_certificate": false,
    "pending_update_count": 0,
    "max_connections": 40,
    "ip_address": "35.000.00.000",
    "allowed_updates": [
      "message"
    ]
  }
}

Then Telegram does send updates right after my call, kinda when I remind about myself. Imagine the case:

No pending updates
Write a message to the bot
No requests, no logs, no events in GCP
Wait a long period of N hours
call getWebhookInfo
it returns pending update 1 and calls me

Update:

the app when it starts upon request calls setWebhookMethod and in most cases, it returns Webhook is already set but sometimes it returns Webhook was set which means

Telegram forgets about my webhook in unknown circumstances. Though my bot doesn't call the deleteWebhook endpoint



What can be wrong?
I don't have any firewall rule other than default.
The certificate is okay as it's managed by Google.
I tried with a static IP (load balancer) and w/o - same case.
I thought it's about "allowed_updates": [ "message" ] but no - it's set now always and no updates.


Have you tried to test it with local environment or other environment? ( It can help to localize the problem)

@NickVee this should be something infra related. It's so stupid that when I call get TG calls me

I couldn't figure out the exact reason. I tried using static IP too but it didn't help either.
The closet assumption is that my bot, given the framework I use - kotlin-telegram, sets the webhook during the actual webhook request from Telegram (it does it during the application startup and I have it serverless, it starts e).
I did the following workaround:

I stopped setting the webhook during the application startup
I started setting the webhook outside in a scheduled job (GCP Scheduling + GCP cloud functions)

